# Count rows with column varbinary NOT NULL tooks a lot of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-express

This query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Table 
WHERE [Column] IS NOT NULL
```

takes a lot of time. The table has 5000 rows, and the column is of type `VARBINARY(MAX)`.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you try SELECT COUNT(1)...

Comment: @ibram There is no difference between count(*) vs count(1).

Comment: `select count([Column]) from table` will return the same count. Is there any index for that column?

Comment: @jarlh That will exclude `null` vaules in that column... So the count may change.

Comment: With such a simple query, the problem is going to be `[column] IS NOT NULL` rather than the `COUNT(*)` (which is a very simple operation for SQL Server). You're not going to be able to really index a `varbinary(MAX)` column, however, as it can hold a large amount of data. Out of interest, does the SQL Instance have much resource available?

Comment: @Sankar, that's the point! (The WHERE is no longer needed in my case.)

Comment: @Sankar `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table] WHERE [Column] IS NOT NULL;` and `SELECT COUNT([Column] FROM [Table];` are synonymous.

Comment: Sorry i didn't see that

Comment: I imagine you could have some other running queries slowing it down. To ignore the locks try:   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table] WITH (nolock) WHERE[Column] Is Not Null

Comment: Most certainly your query is *blocked*. Find out who is blocking it and why http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs to do a table scan on a column that can potentially be very large without any way to index it. There isn't much you can do to fix this without changing your approach.

One option is to split the table into two tables. The first table could have all the details you have now in it and the second table would have just the file. You can make this a 1-1 table to ensure data is not duplicated.

[image: Table ERD]

You would only add the binary data as needed into the second table. If it is not needed anymore, you simply delete the record. This will allow you to simply write a `JOIN` query to get the information you are looking for.

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Table1
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2
    ON Table1.Id = Table2.Id
```